# building an alias from a function

Tags: bash, alias, eval

I need a lot of different aliases to create ssh tunnels to different servers. To give you a few of them:

```
alias tunnel_1='autossh -M 20000 -N -L 8080:localhost:8080 -N -L 9200:localhost:9200 -N -L 8090:localhost:8090 user@server1.xx'
alias tunnel_2='autossh -M 20000 -N -L 8000:localhost:8080 -N -L 9200:localhost:9200 -N -L 8090:localhost:8090 user@server2.xx'
```

I came up with this function I added in my aliases :

```
addPort () {
  echo "-N -L $1:localhost:$1 "
}

tunnel () {
  aliasString="autossh -M 20000 "
  for port in "${@:2}"
  do
    aliasString+=$(addPort $port)
  done
  aliasString+="$1"
  eval $aliasString
}
```

so I just need to do this to tunnel to the server I want:

```
tunnel abc@domain.com 8080 9000 7200
```

It’s working well, But I’d like not to use eval if it’s possible.
is there another way to call `autossh` directly and give it the correct params without using eval?

Comment: You don't need to add `-N` along with each tunnel. BTW, do you consistently tunnel the same ports to a bunch of different servers? If so, how about creating a wildcard `Host` entry in ~/.ssh/config, with the appropriate [`LocalForward` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146457/ssh-port-forwarding-in-a-ssh-config-file)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a single shell function:

```bash
tunnel () {
    local host="$1"; shift
    local port
    local args

    args=( -M 20000 )

    for port do
        args+=( -N -L "$port:localhost:$port" )
    done

    autossh "${args[@]}" "$host"
}
```

or, for `/bin/sh`:

```sh
tunnel () {
    host="$1"; shift

    for port do
        set -- "$@" -N -L "$port:localhost:$port"
        shift
    done

    autossh -M 20000 "$@" "$host"
}
```

Both of these functions extracts the first argument into the variable `host`, and then builds a list consisting of strings made up from the provided port numbers.

At the end, both functions invoke `autossh` with the given list and the host.

Comment: How does `port` get initialized to `$2` `$3` … ?

Comment: @Albizia The loop loops through them. You could write the loop as `for port in "$@"; do ...; done` too, if that feels better (but then you have to remember to double quote `$@` as `"$@"`).

Answer (score 4):

`aliasString` doesn't contain any shell special characters other than whitespace. So `eval $aliasString`, `eval "$aliasString"` and `$aliasString` are all equivalent. The [unquoted variable substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) `aliasString` performs word splitting and wildcard expansion; since there are no wildcards, that's just word splitting. `eval "$aliasString"` performs all the shell parsing and evaluation steps; since there are no special characters other than whitespace, the only thing that happens is word splitting. `eval $aliasString` does the word splitting from the unquoted variable substitution, then joins the words together with a space in between, and then does the whole shell evaluation which splits the words again.

Here's a simpler way to write this function in plain sh.

```
tunnel () {
  command=$1
  shift
  for port do
    command="-N -L "$port:localhost:$port $command"
  done
  autossh -M 20000 $command
}
```

Note that this only works with parameters that don't contain any whitespace wildcard characters. See [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/540062) for more robust methods.

Shell aliases are not involved at all.